# Zend index action parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I want to have url `example.com/invoice/id/5`

Create action

```
function indexAction(){
  echo "test";
}
```

Now i try access this action from url

`example.com/invoice/` or `example.com/invoice/index`

And also pass parameters

```
example.com/invoice/id/5
```

Here I'm get error because Zend try to render

```
id.phtml
```

My question is how to have url `example.com/invoice/id/5` and not use `example.com/invoice/index/id/5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default Zend Route as Follows:
    http://www.example.com/controller/action/param_name/param_value/param_name_1/param_name_1_value

For the custom URL, you have to define the routes in the Bootstrap.php as of Zf1.

$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();

```
    $router->addRoute(
                'someidentifier',
                new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    '/invoice/:id',
                    array(
                        'controller'=>'invoice',
                        'action'=>'index'
                    )
                )
        );
```

If it is ZF2 I think you have to define the custom route in Module.php, onBootstrap function and attach to eventManager.

Comment: Add this to controller action method ?

Comment: Nope.  If it is ZF1 you are using, you need to add the code to Bootstrap.php -> Method _initRoutes().  What you do in controller is you just need to add index action, and $this->getParam('id') will get the ID.